# Error in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I want to solve this nonlinear equation in the "NDSolve".
The matrixs of this equation are defined as below.

```
a={{-0.0122811, 2.00362, 0., 0., -0.000831176, -0.0314881, -1.98759, 
0., -2.61853, 0., 0.0684041, -0.153004}, {-4.76347, -0.0162208, 0., 
0., 4.7423, 4.7423, -0.0622047, 0., -6.92706, 0., 0.163538, 
0.100898}, {0., 0., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 
0., 0., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -302.3, 0., 0.}, {-0.00385179, 
0.628406, 0., 0., -0.000838648, 0.000129341, -0.623379, 
0., -0.821264, 0., 0.021454, -0.0479874}, {-0.00424307, 0.692242, 
0., 0., 3.76098*10^-6, -0.031758, -0.686704, 0., -0.904691, 0., 
0.0236333, -0.0528621}, {-2.55204, -0.00869036, 0., 0., 2.5407, 
2.5407, -0.0627063, 0., -3.71119, 0., 0.0876161, 0.0540563}, {0., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -0.01, 0.2, 0.2, 0., 0.}, {60067.7, 120309.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -74137.5, -4065.04, 0., 1.80926*10^-18, 
79975.4}, {0., 0., 0., 134470., 0., 0., 0., 128410., 0., -4065.04, 
0., 0.}, {0.00682811, -0.153744, 0., 0., -0.015295, -0.015295, 
0.137188, 0., 0., 0., -0.645212, 0.}, {4.1239*10^6, -2.05898*10^6, 
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -4.40159*10^6, 42.5013, 0., 1., -1.5868*10^6}};

b={{0.}, {0.}, {0.}, {0.}, {0.}, {0.}, {0.}, {0.}, {79975.5}, {0.}, \
{0.}, {-1.58273*10^6}};

c={{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}};

q={{1}};
r={{1}};

rs = NDSolve[{

p'[t] + p[t].a + Transpose[a].p[t] - 
p[t].b.Inverse[r].Transpose[b].p[t] + Transpose[c].q.c == {0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

, p[0] == {0, 1, .1, .2, .5, .01, .4, 0, .32, .12, .2, .11}}, 
p, {t, 0, tf}]
```

but I get the following error:

```
NDSolve::overdet: "There are fewer dependent variables, {p[t]}, than  equations, so the system is overdetermined. "
```

Please help me to identify the error.

Comment: What are the values of `a`, `b` and `c`? Also, what is `q` and `r`?

Comment: q=r=(1) and  the values of a,b,c are random.

Comment: Please edit your question such that one can copy and past the problem setup and get the same message as you.

Comment: I'm suspecting that something may be wrong with your equation, since all terms except of `Transpose[c].q.c` are vectors of length $12$ whereas the later is (zero!) matrix of size $12\times 12$. If one skpis this last term (I don't know whether it is correct) then `NDSolve` gives a solution but complains about the sifness of this ODE system.

Answer (score 1):

OK, look at the following:

```
showStatus[status_] := 
  LinkWrite[$ParentLink, 
   SetNotebookStatusLine[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], 
    ToString[status]]];
clearStatus[] := showStatus[""];
clearStatus[]

rs = NDSolveValue[{IdentityMatrix[Length[a]].p'[t] + p[t].a + 
      Transpose[a].p[t] - p[t].b.Inverse[r].Transpose[b].p[t] == {0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} // N, 
   p[0] == {0, 1, .1, .2, .5, .01, .4, 0, .32, .12, .2, .11} // N}, 
  p, {t, 0, 1},
  EvaluationMonitor :> showStatus["t = " <> ToString[CForm[t]]]]
```

This will integrate but the system is stiff. If you remove the `- p[t].b.Inverse[r].Transpose[b].p[t]` things will integrate much further. Also, note that this

```
Transpose[c].q.c
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

is not correct as a part of the equation - probably you meant to include the dependent with it?